# Where can I find drawings or diagrams of the Boeing 737-800's internal layout?

Tags: aircraft-systems, boeing-737

I am working on an alternative fuel system for my final school research. I am applying it to the 737-800. Now I could not find info on how the internals are situated. Of course pictures of the cabin are widely available. However I am looking for drawings, pictures or graphs on the cargo compartment, systems placement like gear, hydraulics, pumps or whatever. Basically the whole internal volume and what it is occupied by.

This is maybe a bit demanding but any info is really helpful.

Comment: This is a Q&A website, thus you may ask a clear and specific question (e.g. where can I find drawing and blueprint of B737-800?)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If there are blueprints that show internal space division, then yes please! I would love to see those.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear, although documents more specific than @Daniel's answer may be hard to find. A "how it's made" 3D picture with cut-away drawings of the internals may be your best source, even if you have to estimate some of the dimensions.

Comment: Some of this information is in the aircraft maintenance manual (AMM) ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywaux.png)).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the "Airplane characteristics for airport planning" document for the 737, espcially from page 47: http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/airports/acaps/737.pdf

These kind of documents are created by the airplane manufacturer and are often publically available.